# Running total with arguments - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple adding function here. I start a count at 0. I want to add the argument of add_credits(x) to the credit total, to keep a running total.  A for loop doesn't seem like the right thing to use here, since I don't know how many times I'll be looping.

So what I want to do here is, add 3. Credits = 3.  Add 4, credits = 7.

```
credits = 0
def add_credits(x):
    new_total = credits + x
    return new_total

print (add_credits(3))
print (add_credits(4))
```

I know the solution must be really simple... I feel like an idiot.

Comment: Functions aren't meant to be used like this. You'd be better served by making a class instead.

Comment: You never even *try* to change the value of `credits`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams why are functions not meant to be used like this?

Comment: They are meant to optionally accept arguments and return a result, without side effects. There are other constructs that can be used if side effects are required.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a class to represent some sort of "Wallet" object. This will hold an attribute of `total` and an `add` function:

```
class Wallet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0

    def add_to_total(self, amount):
        self.total += amount


wallet = Wallet()
wallet.add_to_total(5)
print(wallet.total) # outputs 5
```

Answer (score 1):

in your example, the `credits` variable in the function is a `local` variable. This means it does not share the same value you assigned it at the top. You need to identify it as global for it to work like this:

```
credits = 0
def add_credits(x):
    global credits
    credits = credits + x
    return credits 

print (add_credits(3))
print (add_credits(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Code within a function will not change the value of a variable passed to it when the variable represents an int.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to increment the `credits` variable within the function, you can use `global`:

```
credits = 0


def add_credits(x):
    global credits
    credits += x


add_credits(3)
print(credits) # 3

add_credits(4)
print(credits) # 7
```

But using `global` in this way is not recommended, so I would definitely use [Evyatar's solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48846503/7742282)